# Set real transparency of a label

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, label, transparency

I'm coding a winform application in c++/cli.
In this app I have a graph on a `pictureBox` and, to point some interesting data, I'm using a marker coded as a `label`. To achieve transparency, I have set:

```
label1->Parent = picbureBox1;
```

and set the `BackColor` to `Transparent` but I noticed it is a real transparency because it is not transparent to lines drew on the `pictureBox` but only to the background. This is what happens:

```
              /                   1  |                  /          2
             /      ---------        |                 
            /       |label1 |        |              |label1|
           /        ---------        |
          /                          |              /
```

Even if it is transparent, my label covers the line when the label moves from 1 to 2.
What I would like to achieve is this:

```
              /                   1  |                  /          2
             /      ---------        |                 /
            /       |label1 |        |              |label1|
           /        ---------        |               /
          /                          |              /
```

Is this possible or should I redraw the line when the marker covers it?

Comment: Transparency is not what you think it is. When you write `label1->Parent = pictureBox1;` it is translated to `label1->backColor = pictureBox1->backColor`. The label control doesnt know about the drawings on the picturebox. So, yes, you have to draw the remaining line in the **label**

Comment: This happens when you draw by using CreateGraphics().  Always wrong, draw with the Paint event handler.

Comment: Ok, it seems clear. I just thought about that, I hoped there was a way to not write more code! :p @HansPassant: I'm not using CreateGraphics this time, it won't help me drawing with Paint event handler in this case!

Comment: Your question is just too poorly documented to have a shot at guessing at the problem.  Next blind guess is not passing *true* to the Invalidate() call.  Don't make us guess, post code instead of ascii art.